# How to call "setOnClickListener" method by multiple views?

Tags: java, android

I have multiple `Textviews`, in my `activity_main.xml` page.
I declared just one `OnClickListener` to use for all Textviews as below:

```
public class NumbersClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    String text = "";


    @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

and then , I want to call this method from multiple views. as below code:

```
TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
textview1 .setOnClickListener(clickListener);
TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
textview2 .setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

so how could make different Toast for different Views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find your current view which is clicked in `onClick(View view)` method with:

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view){

        if(view.getId() == R.id.textView1){
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Hi First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if(view.getId() == R.id.textView2){
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Hi Second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is ok.Thank you

Comment: By the way,how could open that view(activity),Simultaneously?

Comment: What? I did not get the question.

Comment: I mean after click on textview1,a Toast appears but how i can,open textview1 activity Simultaneously?

Comment: @M.JJalali You can only start one activity at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your activity implement `View.OnClickListener` interface and override `onClick()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    .....................
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.textview1:
                 // 
                 break;
            case R.id.textview1:
                 // 
                 break;
    }
}
```

For each view you set the listener like this:

```
textview1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Another way is to define your custom listener:

```
View.OnClickListener myCustomLIstener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId()) {
           case R.id.view1:
               // 
               break;
           case R.id.view2:
               // 
               break;
    }
};
```

and set it:

```
textview1.setOnClickListener(myCustomLIstener);
```